# Load a CJS module config inside another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, mjs

I'm trying to load a config inside a node module but I'm not sure which is a good practice to do it, I have this scenario:

A config `my.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{tsx,ts}',
  ],
}
```

Then I have a module `cli.mjs` is supposed to load it:

```
import arg from 'arg'
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises'
import path from 'path'

let configPath = './my.config.js'

const args = arg({
  '--config': String,
  '-c': '--config',
})

if (args['--config']) {
  configPath = args['--config']
}

console.log(readFile(path.resolve(configPath), { encoding: 'utf8' }))
```

This will just return a simple **string** with my config inside, not a javascript object:

```
`
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{tsx,ts}',
  ],
}
`
```

How should I load my config in the right way?

I've saw basically everyone use configs like that in [TypeScript](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil) or [CJS projects](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss), but it's hard to me see how and where they parse these configs, probably I'm missing some basic information about this?

Comment: Why are are you writing your config file as a CJS module if you're otherwise using ECMAScript modules?

Comment: I'm not used to work with node so probably this is not a good response, I would write it as CJS module cause I'll use it with postcss and I've saw the standard configs passed to it are CJS modules.

Comment: Have you read https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs? Don't read the configuration as a text file, but `import` or [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename) it.